# Can PHP resize an image that is on a remote server?

Tags: php, image

If I only have the url for the image, can PHP still resize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script can download it first, then resize it and store it locally. It can't change files on the remote server.

Check out the [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) and [image](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) functions.